# How many num_workers in DataLoader?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a machine with 1500 Gb of ram and 112 cores but no GPU. I would like to know how to calculate suitable number of `num_workers` in DataLoader and batch size.

I have to make the inference with Inception-v3(pytorch) on 80,000,000 images.
I tried with a batch size of 30k and `num_workers = 4` with fine results. if I try with `num_workers = 50` I don't get a good result

Comment: It's going to depend on things like how large your batches are, and how fast your hard disk is. The best way I've found is to profile with different numbers. Time the average time it takes to get from the end of your inference loop to the beginning of your inference loop (this is how long the system is waiting for the data loader). Use the minimum number of workers that minimizes that time provided it doesn't slow down the inference too much. Generally it doesn't make sense to have more workers than your batch size tho that's not an issue here.